# MongoDB Typescript Error "Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

As one of my GraphQL resolvers, I have this function in which it adds an Artist ID to a user's Liked Artists Object ID array. The code is as follows:

```
async likeArtist(_parent, args, _context, _info) {
      await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: args.userID },
        { $push: { likedArtists: new ObjectId(args.artistID as string) } },
        {
          new: true,
          runValidators: true,
        }
      );
      return true;
    },
```

When I try it out on the actual website, it seems to be working fine. The weird thing is that the line where $push is is throwing an error, specifically at "likedArtists" saying:

```
... gave the following error.
Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

This is the User's Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  image: String,
  email: String,
  posts: Array,
  likedPosts: Array,
  likedArtists: Array,
  balance: String,
  notifications: Array,
  tutorial: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  name: String,
  age: String,
  country: String,
  birthday: String,
  phone: String,
  newUser: Boolean,
  notifRead: Boolean,
  artLevel: String,
  artStyles: Array,
  artKinds: Array,
  userBio: String,
  // More to come
});

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

How do I remove the typescript error? It's getting in the way when I try to `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add typing info for your model. An example taken from the blog:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true }
});

// Export the model and return your IUser interface
export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Reference: https://tomanagle.medium.com/strongly-typed-models-with-mongoose-and-typescript-7bc2f7197722

Comment: Sadly, this code didn't exactly solve the problem as it added more problems like ```findOneAndUpdate``` having an error saying that it has no call signatures. The original problem didn't disappear either. I had a workaround for this by setting the type to 'never' as a temporary fix for now. Thanks